# grid view is not displaying in asp.net . in datatable there is data but not displaying gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

gridview is not displaying in my page.In data table data is coming but grid view is not displaying.

code behind

```
   private void BindProducts()
        {
              using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kernelCS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                // using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_FillData", con))

                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_price", con))
                {
                    //  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                    dt1.Load(cmd1.ExecuteReader());
                    gridviewProducts.DataSource = dt1;
                    gridviewProducts.DataBind();


                }
            }

            }

    aspx code
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewProducts" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and see your `dt1` _really_ has rows?

Comment: As you've not added `BoundFields` so trun on the `AutoGenerateColumns`. e.g `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`

Comment: dt1 has rows. but not grid view displaying

Comment: Are you sure that you called `BindProducts();` from `Page_Load`? Because there is nothing here that prevent `GridView` from displaying data!

Comment: Use SqlDataAdapter for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag the table from the server explorer to the page.

Comment: Please don't use all uppercase; it is perceived as SHOUTING.

Comment: thanks...everything i tried it was not worked , but when i drag and dropped grid view from tool box its worked.....even though both gridview looking same

Answer (score 0):

Try to set AutoGenerateColumns="true". You don't have any columns in your grid.

Comment: i tried   AutoGenerateColumns="true". but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Either set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` or use `BoundField` or 'ItemTemplate'.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) is a sample.

Comment: i tried   AutoGenerateColumns="true". but did not work

Comment: Is there any exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code:

```
 private void BindProducts()
 {
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kernelCS"].ConnectionString);
 con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter   Gridad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_price", con);
 DataTable  Gridds = new DataTable();                 
 Gridds.Clear();
 Gridad.Fill(Gridds);
 gridviewProducts.DataSource = Gridds;
 con.Close();
 }
```

Make sure that AutoGenerate Columns Property to true